# Oracle SQL - Left Join on 1:M relationship between tables and incorrect data output

Tags: sql, oracle, join, distinct

I'm want to join multiple tables using a left join. I'm currently getting duplicate records and inconsistent data across joins. Any ideas?

I believe that I found a solution for the duplicate records, but I'm not sure that it will be reliable.

In this example, when an order is placed, it should attach to any items that are associated with the order and any clients that are associated with the invoice. The Items and Client tables are basically static and only get updated whenever new Items or Clients are added, which is not often.

This is a small scale example, the entire data set is about 6 million rows.

Orders has a 1:M relationship with Orders Detail Level

Invoice has a M:1 relationship with Orders and M:M with Orders Detail Level

Client is only associated with Invoice with a 1:1 relationship

Items has a 1:M relationship with Orders Detail

`SELECT DISTINCT
row_number() over (partition by a.apk order by a.apk desc) as SEQNUM
FROM table
WHERE SEQNUM = 1`

Current Solution

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.apk
,a.DATE
,bc.CATEGORY
,bc.ITEMNAME
,bc.amt
,d.clientname
,e.invoiceid
,row_number() over (partition by a.apk order by a.apk desc) as SEQNUM
FROM atable a 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
     tableb.amt
     ,tableb.apk
     ,tablec.CATEGORY
     ,tablec.ITEMNAME
     FROM tableb b 
        LEFT JOIN tablec c ON (b.cpk = c.cpk)) bc
     ON (a.apk = bc.apk)
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
     d.clientname
     ,e.invoiceid
     ,e.epk
     ,d.dpk
     FROM tabled d 
        LEFT JOIN tableE e ON (d.dpk = e.epk)) ed
     ON (a.apk = ed.apk)
WHERE SEQNUM = 1
```

Sample Data

Table A (Orders) `Primary Key: apk`

```
apk  DATE      
1    8/17/17
```

Table B (Orders Detail Level) `Primary Key: bpk`

```
bpk  apk  cpk amt
1    1    1   5
2    1    2   100
```

Table C (Items) `Primary Key: cpk`

```
cpk ITEMNAME     ITEMID  CATEGORY    
1   Tape         1234    Office Supplies   
2   Toner        5678    Printer Supplies
```

Table D (Clients) `Primary Key: dpk`

```
dpk  CLIENTNAME
5    STAPLES
6    WALMART
```

Table E (Invoice) `Primary Key: epk`

```
epk apk dpk INVOICEID  INVOICE_DATE
1   1   5   776        8/18/17
2   1   6   934        8/19/17
```

Current Results

```
apk DATE    CATEGORY        ITEMNAME  amt    CLIENTNAME    INVOICEID
1   8/17/17 Office Supplies Tape      5      Staples       776       
1   8/17/17 Office Supplies Tape      100    Walmart       934
1   8/17/17 Office Supplies Tape      5      Staples       776       
1   8/17/17 Office Supplies Tape      100    Walmart       934
1   8/17/17 Office Supplies Tape      100    Walmart       934       
1   8/17/17 Office Supplies Tape      100    Walmart       934
```

Expected Results

```
apk DATE    CATEGORY         ITEMNAME     amt    CLIENTNAME    INVOICEID
1   8/17/17 Office Supplies  Tape         5      Staples       776       
1   8/17/17 Printer Supplies Toner        100    Walmart       934
```

Thanks in advance!

edit: data, clarification

Comment: I do not understand how you decide to pick values in the last two attributes of your expected result. There are two options for `apk` 1 (staples and wallmart), therefore, why the first row has staples, the second walmart and the second even bounty (combined with 934 belonging to walmart)?

Comment: Actually, if you perform just inner joins then you get 6 rows. It is not clear from your answer how your expected result is created.

Comment: This question makes no sense. For instance, in your table data "Tape" has cpk=1, for which one amt value is known: 3, yet in your current and desired output you link "Tape" with an amount of 5. "Paper towels" only occur with an amount of 100, yet in your desired output you want 3!?

Comment: @RadimBača This is how our data is set up on my end. So for instance, one invoice may contain multiple items and each item is associated with a client. I was trying to replicate the way it looks on my end. Apologies for any confusion there. I've removed the third item for clarification.

Comment: @trincot I've removed the third item and adjusted accordingly. I'm just confused to why when pulling any data that it would pull incorrect item name and category on all of the rows.

Comment: Your database design seems wrong. The sold quantities (b) of items (c) are linked to a date (a), but they should instead be linked to an invoice (e), and there you would find the link to the date (a). And since you have multiple invoices (e) on the same date (a), you cannot know with your schema which sold quantity (b) belongs to which invoice (e). A good query will still link each article to both invoices (e) -- and thus to both clients (d).

Comment: You have error in this table Table E (Invoice) Primary Key: epk

epk apk dpk INVOICEID
1   1   5   776
2   1   6   934

You should use cpk instead of apk.

Comment: @trincot I went back and checked against the database I'm using on my end and it seems to be that Invoice has a 1:M relationship with Orders and a M:M relationship with Orders Detail Level, but only connects using apk where apk doesn't have any duplicate values in Orders. For every order that is placed, it should grab any items from the items table and any clients associated with that invoice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You should add `bpk` to `invoice` table or `epk` to `order details` to create connection between these tables. Otherwise we don't know if Toner was ordered by Staples or Wallmart.

But in current data model, assuming that first item in `order details` matches first position in `invoice` we can use `row_number()`. By "first" I mean with lower id:

```
select apk, adate, category, itemname, amt, clientname, invoiceid
  from a
  join (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by apk order by bpk) rn 
          from b) b using (apk)
  join c using (cpk)
  join (select e.*, row_number() over (partition by apk order by epk) rn 
          from e) e using (apk, rn)
  join d using (dpk)
```

Demo:

```
with 
    -- orders
    a (apk, adate) as (  
        select 1, date '2017-08-17' from dual),
    -- order details
    b (bpk, apk, cpk, amt) as (
        select 1, 1, 1,   5 from dual union all
        select 2, 1, 2, 100 from dual),
    -- items
    c (cpk, itemname, itemid, category) as (
        select 1, 'Tape',  1234, 'Office Supplies'  from dual union all
        select 2, 'Toner', 5678, 'Printer Supplies' from dual),
    -- clients
    d (dpk, clientname) as (
        select 5, 'Staples'  from dual union all
        select 6, 'Wallmart' from dual),
    -- invoice
    e (epk, apk, dpk, invoiceid) as (
        select 1, 1, 5, 776 from dual union all
        select 2, 1, 6, 934 from dual)
select apk, adate, category, itemname, amt, clientname, invoiceid
  from a
  join (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by apk order by bpk) rn
          from b) b using (apk)
  join c using (cpk)
  join (select e.*, row_number() over (partition by apk order by epk) rn
          from e) e using (apk, rn)
  join d using (dpk)
```

Result:

```
   APK ADATE       CATEGORY         ITEMNAME        AMT CLIENTNAME  INVOICEID
------ ----------- ---------------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     1 2017-08-17  Office Supplies  Tape              5 Staples           776
     1 2017-08-17  Printer Supplies Toner           100 Wallmart          934
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that INVOICE table has column cpk

```
Table E (Invoice) Primary Key: epk

epk apk cpk dpk INVOICEID
1   1   1   5   776
2   1   2   6   934
```

The SQL Query would be

```
SELECT os.apk,
       os.ord_dt,
       it.category,
       it.itemname,
       od.amt,
       cs.clientname,
       ie.invoiceid
  FROM orders os
 INNER JOIN order_dtl od
    ON os.apk = od.apk
 INNER JOIN items it
    ON od.cpk = it.cpk
 INNER JOIN invoice ie
    ON ie.apk = od.apk
   AND ie.cpk = od.cpk
 INNER JOIN clients cs
    ON cs.dpk = ie.dpk;
```

Result

```
       APK ORD_DT    CATEGORY             ITEMNAME          AMT CLIENTNAME  INVOICEID
---------- --------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 17-AUG-17 Office Supplies      Tape                5 STAPLES           776
         1 17-AUG-17 Printer Supplies     Toner             100 WALMART           934
```